# Gradle Wrapper Update and spring.dependency-management Plugin Error

Tags: gradle, grails, gradlew

I'm using a Grails project and I updated my gradle-wrapper from "gradle-2.9-all" to "gradle-3.0-bin" and I get this error:

> An exception occurred applying plugin request [id:
> 'io.spring.dependency-management', version:` '0.5.2.RELEASE'] Failed
> to apply plugin [id 'io.spring.dependency-management'] Could not
> create task of type 'DependencyManagementReportTask'.

**My build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.5.0'
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:5.0.4"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.5.2.RELEASE"
}

version "1.0.0"
group "project"

apply plugin: "spring-boot"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "asset-pipeline"
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update plugin io.spring.dependency-management to version at least 1.0.0.RELEASE
https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/tree/v1.0.0.RELEASE

Notice that from version 1.0.6.RELEASE spring dropped support for Gradle 3.x